# Group data by state and get percent with dplyr?

Tags: dplyr

How to group customers by state in this data and get percent of customers below using dplyr?:
[customer data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6gsW.png)

```
colsolarestates <- ColSolare %>% group_by(state) %>% summarise(state = n()) %>% mutate(percent = (state) / sum(state)*100)
```

Comment: percent of customers below what? also, please don't post images.  just paste the output of `dput(Colsolare)` into the question ( or `dput(head(Colsolare,30))`)

Answer (score 0):

I've assumed that "customers" is referring to the `customer_type` variable. You can get the percentage of `customer_type` per state by using `group_by` with `.drop = FALSE` in order to capture zeroes. You can also use `label_percent` to place a % add the end of every value.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
set.seed(123)
state <- state.abb %>% as.data.frame() %>% rename(state = 1)
ColSolare <- state %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  rename(state = 1) %>%
  rbind(state, state, state, state) %>%
  mutate(customer_type = sample(
    x = c("bar", "restaurant", "cafe"),
    size = 250,
    replace = TRUE,
    prob = c(.2, .6, .2)
  ))

colsolarestates <- ColSolare %>% 
  mutate(state = factor(state)) %>% mutate(customer_type = factor(customer_type)) %>%
  group_by(state, customer_type, .drop = FALSE) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) %>% 
  mutate(percent = (n) / sum(n)*100) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(percentlabel = scales::label_percent(scale = 1)(percent))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'state'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.

head(colsolarestates)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 5
#>   state customer_type     n percent percentlabel
#>   <fct> <fct>         <int>   <dbl> <chr>       
#> 1 AK    bar               1      20 20%         
#> 2 AK    cafe              1      20 20%         
#> 3 AK    restaurant        3      60 60%         
#> 4 AL    bar               1      20 20%         
#> 5 AL    cafe              0       0 0%          
#> 6 AL    restaurant        4      80 80%
```